# Tablix in Tablix - Header not repeating

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I have one tablix embedded in another tablix. I cannot get the parent tablix's header to repeat when the detail table spans pages.

I have tried numerous methods using the Advanced Mode's **KeepWithGroup** and **RepearOnNewPage** properties with no luck.

I thought I had done this before but I don't remember it being such a pain in the ass.

How can I make the headers repeat?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to make the header repeat in the parent table when the child spans pages so I ended up adding a new header to the child report with the parent's pagination.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the main tablix properties, have you set the Repeat header rows on each page?

[image]

Comment: Yes - I've tried with both Row and Column Headers (I always forget which is which - row headers seems like it would be the header for each row) but there was no change. I've also played with every combination of **Advanced Mode** settings that I could think of.

Comment: Can you do a sub report instead of a nested tablix?

Comment: Yes but I found an easier workaround. I added a new header to the top of the inner table and removed the outer one. I could swear that this worked before though.